# How can I add bug fixes of a library I use in my repository

Tags: git, maven, github

In my maven project I use the library orientdb-1.6.2 . Is there a way to add a bug fix (e.g this one https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/commit/c3fab473c588d91523a582229293dbd14155999e) besides add/remove lines of code manually?

Comment: Fork the repo on github, then clone the forken repo, fix the bug, push it into the forken repo, the open pull request

Comment: In addition to @majioa answer - you may build library with special version (for example "1.6.3-myfix") and deploy to company maven repository or at least to local maven repository and use it by changing origin dependency to your version library in the pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest wayt to fix a bug is:

1. Fork the repo on *Github* by clicking to `Fork` button link;
2. Clone the forken repo:

   ```
   git clone https://...
   ```
3. Fix the bug for that branch, in which you with it be fixed:

   ```
   vim ...
   git add a_fixed_file
   git commit
   ```
4. Push it into the forken repo:

   ```
   git push https://...
   ```
5. Open pull request by clicking to `Pull Request` link;

Comment: I should make the changes in the master branch?

Comment: @salvador you should make changes in those branch you wish, if the bug is in master, yes to master

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I don't want to fix a bug. I want to integrate a bug fix into the current library release. e.g the current release of the library I use (orientdb) is 1.6.4 and I want to integrate [this bug fix](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/commit/c3fab473c588d91523a582229293dbd14155999e)

Comment: The only way is wait for the new release?

Comment: @salvador it depends on the project, have you already commited and accepted the pull request into the upstream? if yes, either wait for a release, or try to use the github code....

Comment: @salvador has my answer been helpful?